# Powershell: If there are files with similar names, delete all but one

Tags: powershell

I have a folder containing .jpg files and .txt files, which all have names like

- text_35_20210101_140235.jpg
- text_36_20210101_140823.jpg
- ...

and the corresponding

- text_35_20210101_140235.txt
- text_36_20210101_140823.jpg
- ...

These names are made up of text_cameraNumber_year/month/day_hour/minutes/seconds.ext (all the files have 20210101 in common).

I wanted to have only pictures from 2 pm so I used

`Remove-Item * -Include *jpg, *txt -Exclude *101_14*`

to delete all of them except the ones at 2 pm.

Now here's the Problem: If I have multiple files with the same cameraNumber at 2 pm, how can I delete all but one with the corresponding .txt file?

Example: If I have

- text_35_20210101_140235.jpg
- text_35_20210101_140543.jpg
- text_36_20210101_140235.jpg

then text_35_20210101_140543.jpg and its .txt file should be deleted, while the other two .jpgs should stay.

I thought using a loop of sorts could limit the amount of .jpg and .txt files with the same cameraNumber and hour value being deleted

Comment: Do you only have files from January 1st, or do you have multiple files for _every day_?

Comment: In this specific folder, yes. I will alter the date used in the script for each day.